# How can I make my database Secure For Mac OS X development?

Tags: database, macos, cocoa, security, core-data

I am developing a Mac OS X application which will contain the user data. Core data/Sqlite are good option for storing the user database. But I want to make sure that the user data is highly secure. So what are the option we have in Mac platform for developing secure database..

Comment: Secure from what sort of attack?

Comment: data in the database should be secure. I mean even if some one say 'X' get the database and if 'X' don't know the password then 'X' should not be able to read the actual data from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options you can use with Core Data. But none of these methods will protect your data when the software is running and the decryption key is "live".

The first option is to use an encrypted disk image to store your database file. This is not necessary on iOS, all the files are encrypted by default, but you can configure some of the encryption aspects for tighter security setups (googling `NSFileProtectionKey`). On OS X, the equivalent technology is FileVault, but it will not be active most of the time, so you shouldn't count on it. So yes, a disk image, mounted when your software is launched and the correct password supplied, unmounted when the software quits. You may want to protect your disk image against an app crash using a helper process watching the main application and unmounting the image if the app crash or quits without unmounting it properly.

The second option is to write a `NSValueTransformer` to encrypt every sensitive attributes in your entities. The protection is at the attribute level here. It may be good enough, or not, and it impacts how the fetch requests work.

The third option is to write your own persistent store (by subclassing `NSAtomicStore`). This is not without consequences tho, that solution must be evaluated carefully.

Besides that, do not forget the basis of course: keychain, key-stretching function like PBKDF2, password salt, stuff like that.

Comment: Could you please explane what do you want to suggest in this line "So yes, a disk image, mounted when your software is launched and the correct password supplied, unmounted when the software quits. You may want to protect your disk image against an app crash using a helper process watching the main application and unmounting the image if the app crash or quits without unmounting it properly."

Comment: I mean something like that as a starting point, through NSTask: hdiutil create -type SPARSE -size 1g -fs HFS+ -encryption -pubkey F534A3B0C2AEE3B988308CC89AA04ABE7FDB5F30 -volname "Vault" -attach "path/vault.dmg"